# ThreeJS: Use a ShaderMaterial as an alphaMap inside a MeshPhongMaterial

Tags: three.js, shader, alpha, phong

Let's say we have a black and white Shader on a sphere.
Is it possible to use it as an alphaMap on a MeshPhongMaterial for another sphere?

Can we use a ShaderMaterial as an alphaMap of a MeshPhongMaterial, like we use a MeshPhongMaterial.map for an alphaMap?

Comment: Yes you can. https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/MeshPhongMaterial.alphaMap

Comment: Nope, MeshPhongMaterial does not accept ShaderMaterial as alphaMap. Atleast on my tests.

Comment: Right. You need to render your shader to a `RenderTarget`. then use the `RenderTarget.texture` as the input texture to your alphaMap. That's the essence [of this demo](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_rtt).

Comment: That looks promising! Thank you for pointing me to the right direction!

Comment: So yeah, I first unwrapped the sphere using this: http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Sphere-Unwrapping.html and now I am gonna get the texture as alphamap.

Comment: Unwrapped and captured in WebGLRenderTarget in a buffer scene, helpful code for that https://codepen.io/tutsplus/pen/eJGzzK